# Discord.js | TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm a beginner at coding. I'm making a node.js today, and it says there's a problem with the embed. I don't know why, but it doesn't work even if I use someone else's code. How should I solve this?

```js
const { Permissions , MessageActionRow , MessageSelectMenu , MessageEmbed,Discord} = require('discord.js')


module.exports = {
name: 'command',
description: 'Embeds',
execute(message, args, Discord) 
    {
const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .setTitle('Yes')
        .setDescription('My Embed')
        .setFooter('life is a lie');

interaction.channel.send({embeds : [embed]})
    },
};
```

This happens. FYI, I shared the code in the Commandz folder, and the index folder had the same error, so I uploaded it. Help me!

Comment: You already deconstructed `MessageEmbed` from the module, where does "`Discord`" come from? Have you tried `new MessageEmbed`

Answer (score 0):

from your code:

```
const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ff0000')
    .setTitle('Yes')
    .setDescription('My Embed')
    .setFooter('life is a lie');

interaction.channel.send({embeds : [embed]})
```

change your `Discord.MessageEmbed()` to `MessageEmbed` since you type from your module as `MessageEmbed`.

Answer (score 0):

You added a const function to newEmbed like this:

`const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()`

But, you put `interaction.channel.send({embeds : [embed]})` instead of `interaction.channel.send({embeds : [newEmbed]})`

What this did was it basically just used the const function and read its value. The `embeds` part is always supposed to be the same, but the `[newEmbed]` part should always be what you declared in your const function for the embed. Remember that for future embeds.

Here's your code modified by me:

```
const { Permissions , MessageActionRow , MessageSelectMenu , MessageEmbed, Discord } = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
name: 'command',
description: 'Embeds',
execute(message, args, Discord) 
    {
const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .setTitle('Yes')
        .setDescription('My Embed')
        .setFooter('life is a lie');

interaction.channel.send({embeds : [newEmbed]})
    },
};
```

Have a good day!